# Program control flow to onDraw()

Tags: android, touch-event, ondraw

I would like to know when will the method

```
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {}
```

will be called. I am asking about **the control flow**.constructor of this class is called from other class.When control comes to the constructor will it simply call all methods in this class??

Also i want to do some drawing when the draw image is touched and moved. for that i used onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event).But i dont know **how to invoke onDraw after i do some coding in onTouch**.That is i do change some coordinate values how will call onDraw to redraw image?

Can anyone help?

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
public DrawView(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3); 
        canvas.drawRect(30, 350, 50, 400, paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
// some other drawings
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://some code
        break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE://some code

            break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP://some code  
    break;
        default:            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply call invalidate method this will call the onDraw method

Comment: @rajesh.adhi from where i have to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/**
 * @author rajeshcp
 */

```
public class SimpleDrag extends View {




private Paint mPaint;
private Rect mRect;

/**
 * @param context  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp 
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    if( mRect != null )
    {
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }
}


private void init()
{
    mRect  = new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
}

private Point mTouchPoint;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp 
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action = event.getAction();

    if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        mTouchPoint = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        if( !mRect.contains(mTouchPoint.x, mTouchPoint.y) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
    {
        final Point curretPoint = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        int xMoved = curretPoint.x - mTouchPoint.x;
        int yMoved = curretPoint.y - mTouchPoint.y;
        mRect.set(mRect.left + xMoved, mRect.top + yMoved, mRect.right + xMoved, mRect.bottom + yMoved);
        mTouchPoint = curretPoint;
        invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}



}
```

Call Invalidate when ever you want onDraw method to get called.

Comment: thnkz. it worked but only in case of ACTION_DOWN. whatever change mentioning in ACTION_DOWN is redrawing  when just touched on the drawn object(not even moved).why its like that?What may be the reason?

Comment: What you really wanna do please explain

Comment: on moving up it should move up and similarly in case of down.But what happened here is whenever touch the object it is redrawing as per MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN.....In switch case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://some code like some change in coordinate values...its working perfectly as you mentioned way.But in case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP / MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE when gave some code(changed coordinate values) it didnt worked.  Same code i just tried with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN it worked there..this is the problem

Comment: Motion.Action_Down means user initial touch down on the screen, Action_move will indicate that user is moving his finger :) and action_up means user finished touch, so what you have to do is u should track the user movement in action_move case and change the x, y position of your react angle or image. Hope this will help.

Comment: now its working.in my code  actually  ontouchEvent  was returning super.onTouchEvent(event).now changed to return true; so it works.thanks.